# Bzr pull does not work

Tags: bazaar, bazaar-plugins

The branch I am trying to pull has a few files which are over 500 mb.

I noticed if I use bzr pull I am unable to download it.

I think the connection is getting a timeout. Is there a way
I can keep the connection alive like set timeout = 30 secs or
something like that?

The error is

```
Write failed: Broken pipehing revisions:Inserting stream:Estimate    
182361/182487                 
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and   
permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail about the error, if any?

Comment: Have you tried several pull commands?

Comment: @TridenT : yes I tried many times and still I have this issue

Comment: @dOxxx: There are no error strange. I have put the pick

Comment: Do you know what is the format of the repository ? bzr **2a** ?

Comment: @TridenT I am not sure but this is the branch  https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1

Comment: Quote : Bazaar repository format 2a (needs bzr 1.16 or later)

Answer (score 0):

A possible **workaround** : pull changes incrementally (retrieve changeset 100 by 100 for example).
This may help to avoid timeout.

```
bzr pull -r 100
```

Just change `100` number to whatever fit your needs, small increments are better !

Pull reference:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/pull-help.html

Comment: Does it solve the issue? What is the result of these commands?